# Setting WebView proxy on Android 4.4.4

Tags: android, android-webview, chromium

I have this code which used to work just fine for setting a proxy programmatically on KitKat however after the 4.4.4 update it appears to not be working. Has anyone else seen this issue? is there a fix? I have confirmed on a different device with 4.4.2 and it still works there. Thanks.

```
private static boolean setProxyKK(WebView webView, String host, int port, String applicationClassName) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Setting proxy with >= 4.4 API.");

        Context appContext = webView.getContext().getApplicationContext();
        System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", host);
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", port + "");
        System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", host);
        System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", port + "");
        try {
            Class applictionCls = Class.forName(applicationClassName);
            Field loadedApkField = applictionCls.getField("mLoadedApk");
            loadedApkField.setAccessible(true);
            Object loadedApk = loadedApkField.get(appContext);
            Class loadedApkCls = Class.forName("android.app.LoadedApk");
            Field receiversField = loadedApkCls.getDeclaredField("mReceivers");
            receiversField.setAccessible(true);
            ArrayMap receivers = (ArrayMap) receiversField.get(loadedApk);
            for (Object receiverMap : receivers.values()) {
                for (Object rec : ((ArrayMap) receiverMap).keySet()) {
                    Class clazz = rec.getClass();
                    if (clazz.getName().contains("ProxyChangeListener")) {
                        Method onReceiveMethod = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("onReceive", Context.class, Intent.class);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Proxy.PROXY_CHANGE_ACTION);

                        /*********** optional, may be need in future *************/
                        final String CLASS_NAME = "android.net.ProxyProperties";
                        Class cls = Class.forName(CLASS_NAME);
                        Constructor constructor = cls.getConstructor(String.class, Integer.TYPE, String.class);
                        constructor.setAccessible(true);
                        Object proxyProperties = constructor.newInstance(host, port, null);
                        intent.putExtra("proxy", (Parcelable) proxyProperties);
                        /*********** optional, may be need in future *************/

                        onReceiveMethod.invoke(rec, appContext, intent);
                    }
                }
            }

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Setting proxy with >= 4.4 API successful!");
            return true;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
            String exceptionAsString = sw.toString();
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, exceptionAsString);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
            String exceptionAsString = sw.toString();
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, exceptionAsString);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
            String exceptionAsString = sw.toString();
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, exceptionAsString);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
            String exceptionAsString = sw.toString();
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, exceptionAsString);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
            String exceptionAsString = sw.toString();
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, exceptionAsString);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
            String exceptionAsString = sw.toString();
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, exceptionAsString);
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
            String exceptionAsString = sw.toString();
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, exceptionAsString);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: What's the exception? Or does the proxy not work?

Comment: There is no exception, it acts like it worked but then the webview doesn't use the proxy.

Comment: It works for me on 4.4.4 Nexus 5

Comment: Interesting, thanks for testing. I'm gonna have to run some more tests, I've only tested on a Nexus 4 with 4.4.4.